# Instance variable that relies on other instance variables

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I want to know the proper way to set a class variable that will be used throughout most/all of the methods in the class, which relies on other class variables and properties being used.

I don't believe I'm able to put this in the constructor because the properties and variable(s) it relies on to be set are not set until after the constructor executes.

I am using asp.net Identity.

**Variable to be set:**

```
private bool userIsSysAdmin;
```

`userIsSysAdmin` would be determined by:

```
userIsSysAdmin = UserManager.GetRoles(user.Id)
      .Any(u => u == "Sys Admin");
```

*Note the use of* `user` *and* `UserManager`

**The class signature, properties and instance variables:**

```
    public class CompanyController : Controller 
    {
       public CompanyController()
       {
       }

       public CompanyController(ApplicationUserManager userManager, ApplicationRoleManager roleManager)
       {
           UserManager = userManager;
           RoleManager = roleManager;
       }

       private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;
       public ApplicationUserManager UserManager
       {
           get
           {
               return _userManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
           }
           private set
           {
               _userManager = value;
           }
       }

       ApplicationUser user = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext()
           .GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>()                               
           .FindById(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId());
```

Comment: To calculate userIsSysAdmin, you just need an instance of UserManager, which is sent to the constructor as a parameter. So you have everything you need to calculate userIsSysAdmin right there in the constructor.

Comment: So should I put `userIsSysAdmin = UserManager.GetRoles(user.Id)
      .Any(u => u == "Sys Admin");` in the constructor `public CompanyController(ApplicationUserManager userManager, ApplicationRoleManager roleManager)` ?

Comment: You can... but looking at your code, there are deeper problems. The problem here is that you can either send through the managers as parameters to the constructors, but you can also set them through properties, and you have no way of knowing which one the user of this class will use. I would get rid of the properties used to set the managers, and only send them into the constructor. That way, you will not have this confusion.

Comment: Also, you will propably end up with cleaner code if you use a dependency injection framework, like Ninject, or Castle.Windsor.

Comment: This is why mvc core implemented [Claims](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/claims)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you need it in almost every method of your controller, that is natural dependency of your class.

In that case, it may be calculated inside controller's constructor. However, you don't want to query your database before you actually need `User` or `UserIsSysAdmin` properties.

So, you can use `Lazy<T>` to solve that issue:

```
public class CompanyController : Controller 
{
    private readonly Lazy<ApplicationUser> user;

    private readonly Lazy<bool> userIsSysAdmin;

    //Not sure why you need parameterless this constructor?
    public CompanyController()
    {
        this.user = new Lazy<ApplicationUser>(() => UserManager.FindById(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId()));
        this.userIsSysAdmin = new Lazy<bool>(() => UserManager.GetRoles(User.Id).Any(u => u == "Sys Admin"));
    }

    public CompanyController(ApplicationUserManager userManager, ApplicationRoleManager roleManager)
    {
        UserManager = userManager;
        RoleManager = roleManager;
        this.user = new Lazy<ApplicationUser>(() => UserManager.FindById(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId()));
        this.userIsSysAdmin = new Lazy<bool>(() => UserManager.GetRoles(User.Id).Any(u => u == "Sys Admin"));
    }

    public ApplicationUser User
    {
        get { return this.user.Value; }
    }

    public bool UserIsSysAdmin
    {
        get { return this.userIsSysAdmin.Value; }
    }

    private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;
    public ApplicationUserManager UserManager
    {
        get
        {
            return _userManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
        }
        private set
        {
            _userManager = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Access modifiers of `User` and `UserIsSysAdmin` properties should be set according to your specific logic and use-case.

Comment: This won't reset `user` when the user manager is written. And unless I'm in a multithreaded environment, I'd prefer a simply lazy loaded property over `Lazy`.

Comment: @Darjan Bogdan Can you explain this comment more: Access modifiers of `User` and `UserIsSysAdmin` properties should be set according to your specific logic and use-case ?

Comment: @amartin well, I made assumption that you want to have that properties publicly available which may not be the case. If you want their visibility only inside your class/object, then you should change them from `public` to something else like `protected` or `private`

Comment: @Darjan Bogdan I found that when I initialize the `user` variable as you've done above, I don't have access to the properties of that class, and it is a field of type `Lazy<ApplicationUser> CompanyController.user` rather than a field of type `ApplicationUser CompanyController.user`. I need access to all of its properties throughout methods in this class.

Comment: @DarjanBogdan I found the issue I was having in the comment above. When using the `Lazy<T>` field you need to access it in the methods by using `.Value`. Things seem to be working now, and I can use `user` and `userIsSysAdmin` in method code as expected. Thanks!

Comment: @Sefe if I remove the constructor `public CompanyController(ApplicationUserManager userManager, ApplicationRoleManager roleManager)` and just use the property for `UserManager` does this resolve the issue you brought up? The Lazy fields would be initialized in the constructor `public CompanyController()`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a lazy loaded property. That means you leave the value uninitialized until the first time you need it. You can also reset the value of user when you set a new user manager. That way you can ensure that the user always matches the user manager.

```
   public ApplicationUserManager UserManager
   {
       get
       {
           return _userManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
       }
       private set
       {
           _userManager = value;
           _user = null;
       }
   }

   ApplicationUser _user;
   private ApplicationUser User
   {
       get
       {
           if (_user == null)
           {
               _user = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext()
                   .GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>()                               
                   .FindById(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId());
           }
           return _user;
       }
   }
```

Comment: Can you explain more? I'm not sure how/why this applies and what to do with it.